# finding distance of a Autocomplete resulted location from current location IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete, distance

I m working on application like Uber and Careem. When user searches for a location using Google Places Autocomplete API, I want to show the distance as well along with the name of the autocomplete resulted place like Uber and Careem does this.

[Plz have a look on this image for further clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiXB4.png)

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Comment: nope @MiteshDobareeya, I went for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

where cuGMS  is array of **GMSAutocompletePrediction**

```
        let cuGMS = self.resultsArray[indexPath.row]

        let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(cuGMS.placeID!, callback: { (response  , error) in

            print("response \(response)")

            if(error == nil)
            { 
                  let coor = response?.coordinate

                  let lat = coor?.latitude

                  let lon = coor?.longitude
            }
            else
            {

            }

        })
```

try this

```
    let loc1:CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 30.0000, longitude:29.2545)

    let loc2:CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 28.02002, longitude:27.00021)

    let dis = loc1.distance(from: loc2)
```

Comment: does Places Autocomplete API returns the coordinates of the location too without reverse geocoding?